# pydev eclipse configuration for __builtins__?

Tags: python, eclipse, configuration, built-in

suppose on **init** I've install my function under **builtins**
then throughout my project I can access it directly that function, no need to import, but how can I tell this to eclipse - so it should not show RED Error "undefined variable"

```
__builtins__['_'] = gettext.gettext
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in Preferences -> PyDev -> Editor -> Code Analysis. There's a bunch of options for adjusting code analysis in there.

On my PyDev, `_` is already in the *Consider the following names as globals* list though - which version of PyDev do you have?

Comment: Thanks, I found in Preferences -> PyDev -> Editor -> Code Analysis -> Undefined, Comma separated values !